# Link to a random page on Yahoo Answers?

Tags: random, yahoo-api

I want to link to a random question within the "resolved questions" section of Yahoo Answers.

I've found some js techniques which involve assigning numbers to each URL so the clicked link chooses randomly from a list I'd create that way. But there are 10's of thousands of resolved questions, and new ones added every day. So that method won't work for me.

How can I link to a random "resolved question?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the Yahoo! Answers API to get the data you need (in either XML or JSON).
The documentation is available here: http://developer.yahoo.com/answers/